# When is the projection from a point on the variety smooth?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup, birational-geometry

Let $X\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ be a smooth irreducible variety (over $\mathbb{C}$) and $p\in\mathbb{P}^n$ a point. Let $\pi:\mathbb{P}^n\setminus\{p\}\to\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ be the linear projection with center $p$ and denote by $Y$ the Zariski closure of $\pi(X\setminus\{p\})$.
I would like to know:

When is $Y$ smooth and the restriction $X\setminus\{p\}\to\pi(X\setminus\{p\})$ of  $\pi$ an isomorphism?

If $p\not\in X$, then I think this is equivalent to $p$ not lying on the secant variety of $X$. But I am mainly interested in the case when $p\in X$. In this case we can rephrase the question as:

When is $Y$ the blow-up of $X$ at $p$?

Comment: If you require $\pi$ being generically one-to-one and the projection center on the variety, then $X$ has degree 2. I think it only happens when $X$ is a smooth quadric hypersurface.

Comment: No, I don't think so. For example if $X$ is the rational normal curve of degree $n$, then $Y$ is the rational normal curve of degree $n-1$ and the restriction of $\pi$ is an isomorphism onto its image. Maybe there was an ambiguity in the question which I edited now.

Comment: Sorry, you’re right. I was thinking about codimension one case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact statement for surfaces is given in Beauville's book: Complex Algebraic Surfaces. Lemma 4.4. I imagine that this generalises easily to higher dimensions.

The condition is different whether or not the point is contained in the variety (as you mentioned), I will state both cases.

I quote exactly from the book, to avoid messing it up:

**Lemma:** Let S be a surface in $\mathbb{P}^N$ and $p \notin S$ (respectively $p \in S$). Let $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{N-1}$  (respectivly $f: \hat{S} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{N-1}$) be the restriction of the projection away from $p$. Then $f$ is an embedding $\iff$ there is no line through $p$ meeting $S$ in at least $2$ (respectively at least $3$) points, counted with multiplicitly.

A nice corollary of this statement (given immediately after in Beauville's book) is that every smooth projective surface is isomorphic to a surface in $\mathbb{CP}^5$.

Comment: Every smooth projective *surface* is isomorphic to a surface in $\mathbb{P}^5$?

Comment: Yes, this is Proposition 4.5 "Complex Algebraic Surfaces". A. Beauville.